# How to work around lack of salesforce wsdl import tag support?

Tags: apex, wsdl2apex, wsdl

**Question**

What techniques can I use to modify a 3rd party WSDL that includes `import` tags so that I can use the Salesforce generate apex class from WSDL feature?

**Background**

I'm a beginner at using WSDLs and I'm trying to implement a 3rd party WSDL on salesforce.  When I try to parse the wsdl I get the error "Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Unsupported Schema element found http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:include. At: 13:54".

I'm making an assumption that this is referring to XMLSchema import tag

```
<xs:import
    namespace="http://ws.clareity.com/clareityStoreFaults"
    schemaLocation="clareityStoreFaults.xsd"></xs:import>
```

Is it possible to flatten the import statement so that the Salesforce WSDL to Apex parse can handle this?  I've done a lot of googling but am having some trouble as I don't know the terminology to describe what I'm looking to do.

I've upload the WSDL and related files in it's entirety into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c1b30a5cb2d6b030a8f2).

Comment: Any joy with this Ralph? Happy to take a deeper look if your still puzzling?

Comment: Not yet @andrew, hoping to spend more time on it tomorrow.  I'm torn between abandoning the approach and just manually consuming the SOAP, or just use a non-salesforce tool to consume the webservice and then have that communicate to Salesforce.  As much as I'd love to get it working natively, in the past i've gotten burned wasting a ton of time working around the shortcomings of Salesforce features with no finished result :(

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: As it stands this doesn't actually work.** You will get the message

> Apex Generation Failed
>   No type specified for element vendorId

Most likely the issue is the missing first import that defines the data types.

---

I was able to get the WSDL to import and generate code by merging the content of `clareityStoreFaults.xsd` directly into the `ClareityStore.wsdl`. Note that I didn't do the same for the http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ import.

So the steps were:

1. Comment out `<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"></xs:import>`
2. Comment out `<xs:import
               namespace="http://ws.clareity.com/clareityStoreFaults"
               schemaLocation="clareityStoreFaults.xsd"></xs:import>`
3. Paste the contents of clareityStoreFaults.xsd xs:schema element under the commented out code from step 2.
4. Import the modified WSDL into Salesforce

I haven't been able to test if it actually works against the web service, but it does import <strike>and generate code</strike>.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll keep hacking away.  I tried a similar approach, and it accepted the file, but didn't generate the code. Got a schema type parameter not found, although it didn't give any detail as to what type was missing.

Comment: It isn't immediately helpful, but there is always Ideas: [Support for SOAP 1.2](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroSAAS). Also [Referencing external schemas in a WSDL](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Referencing-external-schemas-in-a-WSDL/m-p/470999#M86297)